# Refactoring Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [x]) to [].concat(x) throws error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Refactoring `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [x])` to `[].concat(x)` throws this error:

```js
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Moment | [Moment, Moment]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
      Type 'Moment' is missing the following properties from type 'ConcatArray<never>': length, join, slice
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Moment | [Moment, Moment]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
      Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'ConcatArray<never>'.ts(2769)
```

What's the problem I'm missing and how can I refactor this effectively?

Comment: Can you give more context? Where are you calling `[].concat(x)` and what is `x`? Because the refactoring *seems* correct. If it throws an error, it seems like something else is wrong. Can you also verify that `Array` is the global array object and not a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `[]` is typed as `never[]`. But since you call `concat` in the first example on `Array.prototype` which is `any[]`, the concatenation happens between `any[]` and `(typeof x)[]`

> Argument of type 'Moment | [Moment, Moment]'

so you want to normalize that to `Moment[]`?
You can do:

```
let y:Moment[];

y = ([] as any[]).concat(x);

// or something like

y = "length" in x ? x: [x];

// or something completely different, as you are already refactoring.

const [
  from = x,
  to = x
] = x as any;
```

or you put that into a function

```
function foo<T>(arg: T|T[]): T[] {
  return Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg];
}
```